# giving ID and/or other variables for each php page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a simple php coding way how to add variable(s) "dynamic or fixed types" to include in a link so that the link doesn't show up as a clean url. And this an example of what I mean:

```
www.example.com/folder/sense/home
```

To

```
www.example.com/folder/sense/index.php?type=article&id=25&date_written=20100322
```

Or

```
www.example.com/folder/sense/index.php?id=25
```

I hope it is clear what I'm up to.

**P.S:** this is all in Apache

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `http_build_query` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) will convert an array of data into an urlencoded string of variables.

Example from the link above:

```
<?php
$data = array('foo'=>'bar',
          'baz'=>'boom',
          'cow'=>'milk',
          'php'=>'hypertext processor');

echo http_build_query($data) . "\n";
?>
```

will output

```
foo=bar&baz=boom&cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor
```

Comment: Thanks @Dan Murfitt. That was exactly what I was looking for. great job, mate.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i get it, but if you use a form with post, $_POST array will keep variables and they will not be visible in the url

Comment: the question was general to any php page and not necessary to have a form in it. Thanks for the try.

Comment: as I said I didn't get the question, but I figured from the answer